# ASP.NET MVC - Routing and ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionfilterattribute

I am using the below routing for my culture requirements:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SpecificCulture",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    culture = ""
                }
            );
```

And I also have the below filter :

```
public class CultureFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var cultureName = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string) ?? string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureName) && CultureHelper.IsValidCulture(cultureName))
        {
            // e.g if requested cultureName is EN-ZZ the below method will get EN-US
            cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see on the `ActionFilterAttribute` I am getting the approximate culture based on the requested url.

Everything is working fine but I would like to **change the url** also on the above scenario where the user request's the EN-ZZ and I get the EN-US.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to change the browser url, just try:

```
var cultureName = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string) ?? string.Empty;
if (string.Compare(cultureName,"EN-ZZ",true) == 0)
{
    cultureName  = "EN-US";
}
```

if you need to change the browser url, you need to redirect the user:

```
var cultureName = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string) ?? string.Empty;
if (string.Compare(cultureName, "EN-ZZ", true) == 0)
{
     filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] = "EN-US"; //Replace with another culture
     filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(filterContext.RouteData.Values);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureName) && CultureHelper.IsValidCulture(cultureName))
{
        // e.g if requested cultureName is EN-ZZ the below method will get EN-US
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
 }
```